# Test a condition between the request and result of a HTTP request

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

Assume a component method that create a HTTP GET request, sets a loading state while waiting for a response, and removes the loading state when a response is given. For example:

```
getData() {
    this.myService
      .getSomeDate()
      .pipe(tap(_ => {
        this.loading = true;
      }))
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.data = result;
        this.loading = false;
      });
}
```

How would you verify with a test that the state between the request and response (eg. the `pipe` part) is indeed loading? I've tried to use the `HttpTestingController` to send a `HttpEventType.Sent` event but doesn't seems to work. Calling `req.flush()` will cause the code immediately to go to the `subscribe` part so that doens't work either.  This is the test method I've used:

```
it('should have a loading state durin the request', () => {
    component.getData();
    const req = httpClient.expectOne('http://localhost:8080');
    req.event({type: HttpEventType.Sent});

    expect(component.loading).toBe(true);

    req.flush();
    expect(component.loading).toBe(false);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remarks**

1. Please note that `Observable.pipe` is called only when a result value arrives. Therefore, within the `getData` method, the `loading` state should be set to `true` before invoking the `myService.getSomeDateservice` and `pipe` is not needed.
2. When unit testing a `component`, you should mock relevant service methods.

**Component**

```
getData() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.myService.getSomeDate()
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.data = result;
        this.loading = false;
      });
}
```

**Unit Test**

Now you can try to run your test in the fake async zone (using `fakeAsync`) and use `flush` between the two `exec`.

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, flush} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

...

it('should have a loading state durin the request', fakeAsync(() => {
    const myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
    const data = ... // define data to be returned by myService.getSomeDate
    spyOn(myService, 'getSomeDate').and.returnValue(of(data));

    component.getData();

    expect(component.loading).toBe(true);    
    flush();
    expect(component.loading).toBe(false);
}));
```

**UPDATE**

`of` returns an `Observable` that synchronously delivers the values provided as arguments. Therefore, no asynchronous code is actually involved in above test. This makes `flush` useless as mentioned by [Andrei Gătej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9632621/andrei-g%C4%83tej) in the comment below. Through `pipe(delay(1))`, we can simulate the asynchronous processing and will now use `tick` to simulate the asynchronous passage of time.

```
it('should have a loading state durin the request', fakeAsync(() => {    
    ....
    spyOn(myService, 'getSomeDate').and.returnValue(of(data).pipe(delay(1)));

    component.getData();

    expect(component.loading).toBe(true);    
    tick(1);
    expect(component.loading).toBe(false);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! Is `flush` necessary there? Unless `of()` is using other schedulers than `queueScheduler`, `flush` seems a little redundant. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Andrei Gătej: You're right, `of` returns an `Observable` that synchronously delivers the values provided as arguments. So, finally there's no asynchronous code involved in this test.